# Should the [population] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [population](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/population) was created 6 years ago, has 6 views and 85 questions. Its description is extremely vague:

> A population is a complete set of items that share at least one common
>   characteristic

Actual questions seem to range from populating a DB with data to some statistical calculations in R and MATLAB to drawing a graph with D3.js to SSE 4 pop counts (what is even this and how is it related to a population of anything)? Basically, it's a small, unused tag with inconsistent usage.

I also believe that while this tag would be rather relevant and on-topic at Cross Validated, or Biology, or maybe even Philosophy, it doesn't belong to Stack Overflow. The best proof of this is it being effectively abandoned as the statistics in the opening paragraph demonstrate.

So should we remove this little forgotten tag from the population of the existing tags?

Comment: Thank you for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. For more information, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: Title suggestion: Burninate the [population].

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Better title suggestion: .... be depopulated?

Comment: Cull the [tag:population]

Comment: Yes, it should be burninated. The questions about assigning some data to fields and such should probably be retagged to [tag:populate]. If it is used as a *population* of object/people/smths, then it should be removed entirely.

Comment: @Kyll Um... what? Joker seems to already know what their talking about. Nothing their saying conflicts with any normal burnination policy.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think this is meant to be addressed to all readers of this request.  Not the OP specifically.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Or just drop the word "tag" from the current title: "Should the [population] be burninated?"

Comment: @jpmc26 if not for the OP then it is for the passer-by that decide to start removing the tag before anyone had a chance to raise objections or suggest some clean-up/re-tag instructions.